# How to print only non-zeros of a matrix?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have a matrix, but I am trying not to print the 0 values in the matrix. 
I wrote the logic but it is not working.

```
do i=1,42

if (massmat(i,j).ne.0) then

write(20,*)i,(massmat(i,j),j=1,42) 

end if  

end do
```

It still prints out all the zeros and all the values. 
Can someone please help?

Comment: think about what value does j have when you encounter the if statement.

Comment: I am really bad in programming. So pardon my wrong understanding.

Comment: j is the counter for the column, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write

```
do i = 1, 42
   write(20,*) i, pack(massmat(i,:), massmat(i,:)/=0)
end do
```

This will loop over the rows of `massmat` and print all the non-0 elements in each.  I'll leave you to consult your Fortran documentation for details of the `pack` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
write (20,*) pack(massmat,massmat /= 0)
```

prints the nonzero elements.

Answer (score 0):

Let's read through the main `do` loop to see what's going wrong:

```
do i=1,42
```

This will loop over all the columns of the matrix, as you suggested in the comments above.

```
if (massmat(i,j).ne.0) then
```

This line tests whether `massmat(i,j)` is strictly equal to 0. But the value of `j` has not yet been set. In order to test all the elements of the matrix, there should be another `do` statement above that loops over all values of `j`.

```
write(20,*)i,(massmat(i,j),j=1,42)
```

This line writes a single index `i` and an array, which is a column of the matrix. So if the element `massmat(i,j)` is not 0, the entire column containing `massmat(i,j)` is written, even though it may contain elements which are zero. Instead, this line should probably write `i`, `j`, and a single matrix element `massmat(i,j)`, so that only the element which has just been tested will be written.

Comment: To be accurate -- in OP's code and this answer `i` is the row index, not the column index.